# Reading RAW audio file

Tags: c++, audio

I am a beginner in C++ and I have a school project implying analysing an audio file and I can't read the file, in the example the program keeps reading the first value from the file

```
#include <iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream c;
    c.open("cv.RAW");
    int b;
    while(1)
        {
            c>>b;
            cout<<b<<" ";
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Under what circumstances did you believe you'd exit your loop?

Comment: Don't post pics of code or links to pics. [edit] your question and copy/paste the code as text into it.

Comment: `std::cin >> int` is *formatted* input. It's for reading numbers encoded with actual digit characters. .wav files contain binary, so it wouldn't work. Also .wav files contain not only the actual sound data that you want, but also a header with some information about the file. You have to parse the file, or find a library that does it for you.

Answer (score 3):

you need to

1. open your file in binary mode `ifstream c("cv.RAW", std::ios_base::binary)`, if you read a binary file without this flag it will be treated as a text file and will give you incorrect values.
2. check the file is open by checking `if (c.good())` or just `if (c)` before reading any values
3. check the reads succeed by again checking `if (c.good())` or just `if (c)` after reading each byte
4. read using `c.read((char*)&b, sizeof(b))` if you want to read an integer at a time, for a single byte use `char ch; c.read(&ch, sizeof(ch))`

iostreams don't throw exceptions by default so you always need to check their state every time you use them.

Comment: so from my understanding it has to look something like this
'ifstream c("cv.RAW", std::ios_base::binary);
    int b;
    if (c.good())
    while(1)
        {
            c>>b;
            cout<<b<<" ";
            if (!c.good()) break;
        }
    '

Comment: Assuming your file is binary not a text file you still need to change from `>>` to `read()` and your check for good in the while loop needs to be between the read and the print, if the read fails the value in b is undefined (probably the value you read in the last successful read)

Comment: Also don't use plain `int` for the data type, use one with an explicit size such as `int16_t`. Unfortunately you might still have a little-endian/big-endian problem.